# XeLaTex produces no curve with pst-dosage

Tags: xetex, pstricks

When I run XeLateX and want to produce a titration curve with the pst-dosage package (http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pc/pst-dosage/pst-dosage.zip) for only one macro \dosageAfBF it does not draw the curve.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong and need some help.

Here is a simple code :

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-dosage}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\dosageAfBF[pKA=4.75,VA=20,CB=0.1,CA=0.05,dpHunit=0.25,pH1=6,tangentes=true]

\end{document}
```

the output :

[image: the output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Consider registering for being able to fully participate to the site. Nice nickname, by the way: you're one of my preferred painters. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

`xelatex` doesn't work with this package. Use instead `pdflatex --shell-escape` and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-dosage}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}    
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\dosageAfBF[pKA=4.75,VA=20,CB=0.1,CA=0.05,dpHunit=0.25,pH1=6,tangentes=true]

\end{document}
```